# Start using Jupiter SDK, load

Tags: web3.js, jupiter

I try to use Jupiter SDK, but receive

```
incorrect account name during parsing
Error: Failed to parse tick array DVL89XGZmTAZNwvNQHfxUiNVvt4GpBHYn4kT3yoJ8NKP
```

code:

```
this.jupiter = await Jupiter.load({
      connection,
      cluster: 'mainnet-beta',
      user: userPublicKey,
      // or public key
      //platformFeeAndAccounts: platformFeeAndAccounts,
      // routeCacheDuration: CACHE_DURATION_MS
      wrapUnwrapSOL: true,
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed rpc and problem solved